# Is it ok to use serverside API+AJAX instead classic approach in webdev?

Tags: c#, ajax

Recently i read an article which said something similar to "stop using classic approach in web development where server gets data from any datastore and renders the views to browser. server must only retreive needed data end response it via json or whatever so client can render it as he wants". Obviously this approach decreases network traffic + page load would be faster. But on the other hand we have to write more JS code(like Knockout). What's your opinion? What problems can appear in this case?

Comment: Well, ten years ago the prevalent opinion was to do everything on the server side. Some of us probably remember ASP sites where clicking on a checkbox causes the page to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice is valid, but should be less dogmatic. The reason to switch to a data-fetching approach is pretty simple in reality: it allows you to reuse the calls elsewhere, if you have multiple parts of an application requiring the same data. Depending on how you do it, though, you might run into **increased** bandwidth usage due to not being able to get exactly the data you want in one AJAX call (thus duplicating/splitting requests).

The other obvious advantage is it allows you to roll out an outside API pretty easily once that is done.